# Can't push to the back of a list

Tags: c, list, structure

i've been strugeling for some days with this code now, any idea on why my elements are pushed to the back of the list on the second call? T.T

Please I need help desperately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct DLista{
  float val;
  struct DLista *next; //*prev;
}DLista;

void print(DLista *lista){
  DLista *it = lista;
  if(lista == NULL){
    printf("Lista no inicializada\n");
  }else{
    printf("[");
    while(it->next!=NULL){
      printf("%f, ",it->val);
      it = it->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
  }
}

int length(DLista *lista){
  DLista *it = lista;
  int i = 0;
  while(it->next!=NULL){
    it = it->next;
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}

void pushback(DLista **lista, float e){
  DLista *it = *lista;
  if(!length(*lista)){
    (*lista)->val= e;
    printf( "Longitud 0");
  }else{
    while (it->next != NULL){
      printf("%f, ",it->val);
      it = it->next;
    }
    DLista *new;
    new = (DLista*) malloc(sizeof(DLista));
    if (new==NULL) printf( "No hay memoria disponible!\n");

    new->val = e;
    new->next = NULL;

    it->next=new;
  }

}

void pushfront(DLista **lista, float e){
  DLista *new;
  new = (DLista*) malloc(sizeof(DLista));
  if (new==NULL) printf( "No hay memoria disponible!\n");

  new->val = e;
  new->next = *lista;
  *lista = new;
}

int removefront(DLista **lista){
  DLista *new = NULL;
  if((*lista)->next == NULL){
    return 0;
  }else{
    fprintf(stderr,"removing: %f \n",(*lista)->val);
    new = (*lista)->next;
    free(*lista);
    *lista=new;
    return 1;
  }
}

void clear(DLista **lista){
  int i;
  do{
    i = removefront(lista);
  }while(i);
}

void init(DLista **lista){
  *lista = (DLista*) malloc(sizeof(DLista));
  (*lista)->next=NULL;
  (*lista)->val=0;
  fprintf(stderr,"initialized \n");
}

int main(){
  DLista *lista=NULL;
//  lista->next=NULL;
  init (&lista);
  printf("Longitud: %d \n", length(lista));
  pushback(&lista,1.0);
  print(lista);
  pushfront(&lista,2.0);
  pushfront(&lista,3.0);
  print(lista);
  pushback(&lista,5.0);
  print(lista);
  pushback(&lista,7.0);
  print(lista);
  printf("Longitud: %d \n", length(lista));

  printf("Borrado? %d \n", removefront(&lista));
  print(lista);
  printf("Borrado? %d \n", removefront(&lista));
  print(lista);
  printf("Borrado? %d \n", removefront(&lista));
  print(lista);
  clear(&lista);
  print(lista);

  return 0;
}
```

The code would produce this output:

```
initialized 
Longitud: 0 
Longitud 0[]
[3.000000, 2.000000, ]
3.000000, 2.000000, [3.000000, 2.000000, 1.000000, ]
3.000000, 2.000000, 1.000000, [3.000000, 2.000000, 1.000000, 5.000000, ]
Longitud: 4 
removing: 3.000000 
Borrado? 1 
[2.000000, 1.000000, 5.000000, ]
removing: 2.000000 
Borrado? 1 
[1.000000, 5.000000, ]
removing: 1.000000 
Borrado? 1 
[5.000000, ]
removing: 5.000000 
[]
```

Comment: Your length function is off by 1. You initial pushback sets the value of the first node, but the length function returns 0 for a node with no NEXT set.

Comment: @mascoj if you look at the output you'll see that "Longitud 0" is printed meaning the function went into the: 
if(!length(*lista)){
    (*lista)->val= e;
    printf( "Longitud 0");
  }
But then when printed the list remains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any idea on why my elements are pushed to the back of the list on the second call

Looks like you are walking down the `next` of each node till you get to the end of the list.  Then you set the last `next` to the node you are adding.

You are calling `pushback` and it has the `while` loop:

```
while (it->next != NULL){
  printf("%f, ",it->val);
  it = it->next;
```

The first time `pushback` called the list is initialized.  The second call the new node is added to the back.

Comment: Thing is that if i change is to a do{}while(); structure i'll get a segmentation error.

Comment: Your question asks `why my elements are pushed to the back of the list on the second call`.  In the `if(!length(*lista)){` block of `pushback` you do not have a line break on the end of your `printf` statement.  This makes the output a little hard to read.  With this in mind you can see that your print function does not print the list if `next` is null.  The first time something is added to the list the first item `next` is null so nothing is printed out.

Comment: @Manuestaire Please if this solution answers your question please mark it as the answer.  If not, can you provide more information.